# Compare rows across factors in two different dataframes

Tags: r

I have two dataframes that look like this (out of like 150,000 rows):

```
head(df1)
Variable ID
A        ENSG00000185352
A        ENSG00000136267
A        ENSG00000141668
B        ENSG00000154975
B        ENSG00000169855
B        ENSG00000173406
```

```
head(df2)
Variable ID
A          ENSG00000999999
A          ENSG00000136267
A          ENSG00000141668
B          ENSG00000111588
B          ENSG00000000000
B          ENSG00000173987
```

I want to compare the number of different elements in `ID`
are different to df2 `ID`, for the same comparison. For example, the output would be:

```
Comparison  Number of differences
A           1
B           3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
# 1. create sample data --------------------------------------------------------

df1 <- c(
  'A', 'ENSG00000185352',
  'A', 'ENSG00000136267',
  'A', 'ENSG00000141668',
  'B', 'ENSG00000154975',
  'B', 'ENSG00000169855',
  'B', 'ENSG00000173406'
)
df1 <- data.frame(Comparison = df1[ c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11) ], 
                  ID = df1[ c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12) ])

df2 <- c(
  'A', 'ENSG00000999999',
  'A', 'ENSG00000136267',
  'A', 'ENSG00000141668',
  'B', 'ENSG00000111588',
  'B', 'ENSG00000000000',
  'B', 'ENSG00000173987'
)
df2 <- data.frame(Comparison = df2[ c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11) ], 
                  ID = df2[ c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12) ])

# 2. perform row comparisons ---------------------------------------------------

comparisons <- c(df1$Comparison, df2$Comparison) |> 
  unique()
differences <- lapply(comparisons, function(x) {
  idx <- which(df1$Comparison == x)
  d1 <- df1[ idx, 'ID' ]
  idx <- which(df2$Comparison == x)
  d2 <- df2[ idx, 'ID' ]
  setdiff(d1, d2) |> 
    length()
}) |> unlist()
results_df <- data.frame(comparisons, differences) |> 
  `colnames<-`(c('Comparison', 'Number of differences'))

# 3. inspect results -----------------------------------------------------------

View(results_df)
```